# Would anyone give some review on adjoint methods in shape optimization method <in fluid dynamics>?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, optimization

## Modification

Is a continuous adjoint approach a reliable/promising method for optimizing the shape of an airfoil under conditions of unsteady turbulence flow?

## Original Question

I saw lots of people is doing shape optimization of airfoil using optimization theory.

But my feeling is that its effectiveness is very limited, and the formulation in continuous adjoint and programming in discrete adjoint method are all very complicated.

And I do not think it is very promising after a few month's tests and programming. It seems the "improved" shape of surface is very noisy. And many of its assumptions only valid in frozen turbulence.

Could anyone share more his experience on this subject?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel - what exactly are you asking about? A general request for people to share their experience is kind of too vague for this site. Could you edit your question to be more specific?

Comment: Okay, please move as you want. I am sorry I am new here.

Comment: The question isn't what I want but rather (1) if you think you are more likely to get a good answer over there and (2) if the mods over there are willing to have it. I'll ask the mods if they want it.

Comment: The SciComp mods want clarification of the question before they'll consider accepting it, which I think is reasonable.

Comment: The question should be stated "is this a reasonable method, and does it produce optimized airfoils?"

Comment: I'm one of the scicomp mods, it's an interesting question, but I agree that it needs a little more detail/depth.  Unfortunately, the level of specialized knowledge required to answer this for a particular application (aerospace engineering) is not a fit for many of our users.  However, the general concept of PDE-constrained shape optimization is important in the field of computational science, so we will at least be able to comment on that.

Comment: @Aron Ahmadia, thank you for your understanding :)

And yes, the question's background is related to aerospace engineering and CFD.

Comment: Sorry @dmckee, I am new here, I do not know where I can possibly get a good answer, since sometimes it is difficult to judge what category a question belongs or which site the expert would be? :)

Comment: @Daniel: Why don't you make your question precise enough so that it can be answered without specific knowledge of aerospace enginerering. (I think CFD is fine for scicomp.)

Comment: I will do my best, or could you edit it on my behalf. Thanks

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more detail?  What optimization scheme did you use and how did you formulate your objective function?